# How can i make a function that accepts 2 pairs of ranges and checks if even a single time(date) is included in the other range)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I'm trying to create a function in JavaScript that accepts two pairs of date/time ranges and checks if there is any overlap between them. I want the function to return true if even a single moment is included in both ranges, and false otherwise.

Here's an example of the type of input I'm dealing with:

Range 1: ["2023-07-02T09:00:00.000Z", "2023-07-02T17:00:00.000Z"]
Range 2: ["2023-07-02T13:00:00.000Z", "2023-07-02T21:00:00.000Z"]
In this case, the function should return true because there is an overlap between 13:00 and 17:00.

Here's the current function I'm using:

using datefns btw

```
const doTimesIntersect = (
  newStartTime,
  newEndTime,
  blockStart,
  blockEnd
) => {
  return (
    (isAfter(newStartTime, blockStart) && isBefore(newStartTime, blockEnd)) ||
    (isAfter(blockStart, newStartTime) && isBefore(blockStart, newEndTime))
  );
};
```

This doesn't seem to be working properly, and I'm not sure why. Any insights or improvements would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
(isAfter(newStartTime, blockStart) && isBefore(newStartTime, blockEnd))
```

tests if the new range is contained within `[blockStart,blockEnd]`, as well as not sharing either start or end times.

Similarly

```
(isAfter(blockStart, newStartTime) && isBefore(blockStart, newEndTime))
```

);

tests if the block range is contained within the new time range, without sharing start or end times.

Try instead

```
return !(isAfter(newStartTime, blockEnd) || isAfter( blockStart, newEndTime))
```

Note this treats time ranges as overlapping if the end of one range is the same as the start of the other because they have a point of time in common.

---

Some test cases:

```js
const doTimesIntersect = (
  newStartTime,
  newEndTime,
  blockStart,
  blockEnd
) => !(isAfter(newStartTime, blockEnd) || isAfter( blockStart, newEndTime));

const isAfter =  (timeString, refString) => new Date(timeString) > new Date(refString);
const isBefore = (timeString, refString) => new Date(timeString) < new Date(refString);


console.log( doTimesIntersect(  // posted ranges overlap, say true
    "2023-07-02T09:00:00.000Z", "2023-07-02T17:00:00.000Z",
    "2023-07-02T13:00:00.000Z", "2023-07-02T21:00:00.000Z" )
    ,  "// true expected");


console.log( doTimesIntersect(  // newTimeEnd == blockStart, say true
    "2023-07-02T09:00:00.000Z", "2023-07-02T17:00:00.000Z",
    "2023-07-02T17:00:00.000Z", "2023-07-02T21:00:00.000Z")
    ,  "// true expected");

console.log( doTimesIntersect(  // blockStart after newTimeEnd, say false
    "2023-07-02T09:00:00.000Z", "2023-07-02T17:00:00.000Z",
    "2023-07-02T17:00:01.000Z", "2023-07-02T21:00:00.000Z")
    ,  "// false expected");
```